# nhibernate query all objects implementing an interface

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

For example, if you have an Apple : IWhatever, and an Orange : IWhatever and you want to find both of them because they are IWhatevers, what do you need to do in NHibernate?

Is it completely dependent on the HQL or criteria query, or is there something you must do in the mapping also? If there is a mapping requirement, can Fluent NHibernatee support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a UnionSubClass mapping. Unforntunately it is unsuported in Fluent.

You mapping would be something like:

```
<class name="IWhatever" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id">
    </id>

    <union-subclass name="Apple">
        <property name="Bla" type="int"/>
    </union-subclass>

    <union-subclass name="Orange">
        <property name="Bla" type="int"/>
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: You would still have Apples & Orange mapped normally too, or is that kind of nested class mapping THE mapping for the concrete type? Anything special you need to do in your query? Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it's THE mapping :(. As for querying, just go ahead and do a Session.CreateCriteria.For<IWhatever>()

Comment: It looks like this is the way to go. This [Ayende post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-inheritance.aspx) suggests you need to use HiLo for identity when you do this. Another [SO post] backs that up and also suggests a work-around to make it FNH do it. Cheers

Comment: Diego's answer may suit what I need to do best. There are also apparent other mapping options as nicely outlined in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459419/need-help-with-nhibernate-fluent-nhibernate-mapping). Cheers

Comment: Yes, his answer is indeed what you need.

Answer (score 4):

For Criteria, you don't need to map it. Just:

```
session.CreateCriteria<IWhatever>()
       .List<IWhatever>();
```

Keep in mind you'll only be able to query/sort/project on fields that exist in IWhatever.

Comment: nice, I didn't knew you could do that without mapping

Comment: I didn't get this at first. So if I only need Apples & Oranges persisted I can just map those normally and then retrieve them as IWhatevers?? Is there an HQL equivalent? This would be perfect for what I need to do. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you can. HQL is the same, but you have to `<import/>` the interface (see http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-import)

Comment: This example works pretty well. However, since it creates as many individual SQL queries as there are classes that implement the interface, it becomes a problem with paging results. The paging seems to be done for each query. Is there a way to create a query above these queries?

Comment: @Allov: there's no way to automagically page over arbitrary groups of unrelated entities. Use custom SQL for that.

Comment: Can this be implemented in mapping too?