# Fetch related entities castable in their concrete types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to query EF by an interface and get the data castable in their concrete type ?

Let's say I got:

```
public interface IBaseBlock
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContentBlock : IBaseBlock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class VideoBlock : IBaseBlock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    string string VideoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

So, I want to be able to get a list from entity framework based on IBaseBlock and then cast them into their concret types to get the additional data.

Now, I know it's possible to do it with nhibernate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612816/nhibernate-query-all-objects-implementing-an-interface), and I know all it does is create a bunch of SQL queries, but all in one database round trip. I also don't care much for additional data when the query is issued (I don't want to be able to add wheres and order by, etc.) I just need to filter by the common fields (Id and Name).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support querying by interface (EF doesn't support interfaces at all). It supports only mapped entity inheritance. To make it work you must change your `IBaseBlock` interface to `BaseBlock` abstract class and map inheritance (probably TPC). Using inheritance has some other pitfalls. For example primary key of any entity must be unique in the whole inheritance tree.

As a side note EF currently doesn't support multiple queries within single roundtrip so when querying inheritance tree it creates one big query with unions.